# Whats causing this error? TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: discord, bots

Whats causing this error?

TypeError: Client.**init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Here is my code below

```
## install discord.py
## py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py

## install requests
## py -3 -m pip install -U requests

## install qbittorrent-api
## py -3 -m pip install -U qbittorrent-api

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

import qbittorrentapi

def filterBy(TorrentInfo,filterType):
    if TorrentInfo[1]==filterType or filterType=="all":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def filterList(FullList,filterType):
    FilteredList=[]
    for i in range(len(FullList)):
        if filterBy(FullList[i],filterType):
            FilteredList.append(FullList[i])
    SortedList=[]
    for i in range(len(FilteredList)):
        if FilteredList[i][2]!="100%":
            SortedList.append(FilteredList[i])
    SortedList.sort(key=lambda x:float(x[2][:-1]),reverse=True)
    for i in range(len(FilteredList)):
        if FilteredList[i][2]=="100%":
            SortedList.append(FilteredList[i])
    return SortedList

def renameStates(FullList):
    completedList=["uploading","pausedUP","checkingUP","stalledUP","forcedUP"]
    downloadingList=["downloading"]
    missingList=["missingFiles"]
    stalledList=["stalledDL"]
    metaList=["metaDL"]
    queuedList=["queuedDL"]
    pausedList=["pausedDL"]
    for i in range(len(FullList)):
        if FullList[i][3] in completedList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[0]
        elif FullList[i][3] in downloadingList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[1]
        elif FullList[i][3] in missingList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[2]
        elif FullList[i][3] in stalledList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[3]
        elif FullList[i][3] in metaList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[4]
        elif FullList[i][3] in queuedList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[5]
        elif FullList[i][3] in pausedList:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[6]
        else:
            FullList[i][3]=StatusList[7]
    return FullList

def findCompleted(FullList):
    CompletedList=[]
    for i in range(len(FullList)):
        if FullList[i][3]==StatusList[0]: #Completed
            CompletedList.append(FullList[i])
    return CompletedList

def findDownloading(FullList):
    DownloadingList=[]
    for i in range(len(FullList)):
        if FullList[i][3]==StatusList[1]: #Downloading
            DownloadingList.append(FullList[i])
        elif FullList[i][3]==StatusList[3]: #Stalled
            DownloadingList.append(FullList[i])
        elif FullList[i][3]==StatusList[4]: #DownloadingMeta
            DownloadingList.append(FullList[i])
        elif FullList[i][3]==StatusList[5]: #Queued
            DownloadingList.append(FullList[i])
        elif FullList[i][3]==StatusList[6]: #Paused
            DownloadingList.append(FullList[i])
    return DownloadingList

def convertToDiscord(InfoList):
    if not InfoList:
        return NothingDownloading
    maxCharsDiscord=1700
    FinalList=[]
    indexRange=[2,3,4,0]
    for i in range(len(InfoList)):
        FinalList.append([])
        for j in range(len(indexRange)):
            if InfoList[i][indexRange[j]]!="inf":
                FinalList[i].append(InfoList[i][indexRange[j]])
    StringListTwo=convertToString(FinalList)
    StringList=convertToString(FinalList)
    currentLength=len(StringList)
    currentMsg=[]
    while currentLength>0:
        maxLength=StringList[0:maxCharsDiscord].count('\n')
        numChars=findNth(StringList,'\n',maxLength)
        if(StringList[numChars+1:-1].count('\n'))==0:
            currentMsg.append(StringList[:])
        else:
            currentMsg.append(StringList[0:numChars])
        StringList=StringList[numChars+1:-1]
        currentLength=currentLength-maxCharsDiscord
    return currentMsg 

def findNth(String,Substring,Occurence):
    val = -1
    for i in range(0, Occurence):
        val = String.find(Substring, val + 1)
    return val

def convertToString(nonStrList):
    StringList=str(nonStrList)
    if StringList.find(ListSeparator)==-1:
        StringList=StringList.replace("'], ['","\n\n")
        StringList=StringList.replace("']]","")
        StringList=StringList.replace("[['","")
        StringList=StringList.replace("', '",ListSeparator)
    else:
        StringList=StringList.replace("', '","\n\n")
        StringList=StringList.replace("']","")
        StringList=StringList.replace("['","")
    return StringList

def printMessages(DiscordLists):
    if DiscordList!=NothingDownloading:
        for i in range(len(DiscordLists)):
            print(convertToString(DiscordLists[i]))
            print("------------------------------------------------")
    else:
        print(NothingDownloading)
        print("------------------------------------------------")

StatusList = ["Completed","Downloading","Files missing","Stalled","Attempting to start","Queued","Paused","Unknown status"]
ListSeparator = ",    "
NothingDownloading = "Nothing is downloading! Why not request something?"
DownloadingStatus = "downloading"
CompleteStatus = "completed"

#############################
## ENTER YOUR DETAILS HERE ##
#############################

botChannel = "BOT CHANNEL" ## ID CHANNEL OF THE CHANNEL FOR THE BOT TO LISTEN TO ##
tvCategory = "tv-sonarr" ## CATEGORY IN QBIT FOR TV SHOWS ##
movieCategory = "radarr" ## CATEGORY IN QBIT FOR MOVIES ##
qbt_client = qbittorrentapi.Client(host='localhost', port=8080, username='admin', password='password') ## QBIT WEB LOGIN DETAILS ##
TOKEN = "BOT SECRET" ## DISCORD BOT SECRET ##

#############################
#############################
#############################

# the Client will automatically acquire/maintain a logged in state in line with any request.
# therefore, this is not necessary; however, you may want to test the provided login credentials.
try:
    qbt_client.auth_log_in()
except qbittorrentapi.LoginFailed as e:
    print(e)

def updateTorrentList():
    counter = 0
    TorrentList=[]
    for torrent in qbt_client.torrents_info():
        TempList=[]
        TempList.append(torrent.name)
        TempList.append(torrent.category)
        TempList.append(str(round(torrent.progress*100,2))+"%")
        TempList.append(torrent.state)
        TempList.append(convertTime(torrent.eta))
        TorrentList.append(TempList)
        counter=counter+1
    return TorrentList

def convertTime(seconds):
    intervals = (
    ('weeks', 604800),  # 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    ('days', 86400),    # 60 * 60 * 24
    ('hours', 3600),    # 60 * 60
    ('minutes', 60),
    ('seconds', 1),)
    if seconds!=8640000:
        result = []
        for name, count in intervals:
            value = seconds // count
            if value:
                seconds -= value * count
                if value == 1:
                    name = name.rstrip('s')
                result.append("{} {}".format(value, name))
        return 'ETA: '+', '.join(result[:])
    else:
        return "inf"

def updateAll(category,status="all"):
    TorrentList=updateTorrentList()
    FilteredList = filterList(TorrentList,category)
    FinalList=renameStates(FilteredList)
    if status==DownloadingStatus:
        FinalList=findDownloading(FinalList)
    elif status==CompleteStatus:
        FinalList=findCompleted(FinalList)
    DiscordList=convertToDiscord(FinalList)
    return DiscordList
    
print("------------------------------------------------")

print("starting Discord...")
client = discord.Client()
prefix = "$"
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

## BOT VERSION ##

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    print("------------------------------------------------")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command(
        help = "Use this to see the status of what's currently downloading."+"\n"+"If you want to get fancy, you can search for movies/tv shows specifically by type $status movies or $status tv."+"\n"+"You can also see what's completed by doing $status completed, or $status all to see everything."+"\n"+"Finally, you can combine these (like $status tv completed) to only see completed tv shows."+"\n"+"(tip: you can see everything by typing $status all)",
        brief = "Use this to see what's currently downloading"
    )

async def status(ctx, *args):
    channelID=ctx.message.channel.id
    if botChannel==channelID:
        def not_pinned(message):
            return not message.pinned
        await ctx.message.channel.purge(check=not_pinned)
        if "all" in args:
            updateStatus="all"
        elif "completed" in args:
            updateStatus=CompleteStatus
        else:
            updateStatus=DownloadingStatus
        if "movies" in args:
            Category=movieCategory
        elif "tv" in args:
            Category=tvCategory
        else:
            Category="all"
        DiscordList=updateAll(Category,updateStatus)
        if DiscordList!=NothingDownloading:
            for i in range(len(DiscordList)):
                    await ctx.channel.send(DiscordList[i])
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(NothingDownloading)
        
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

can't get my discordbot to run. it worked in the past, but stopped working. it's job is to allow the user to check the status of a requested media download. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

versions of discord.py 2.0 and above require the argument intents.

```py
prefix = "$"
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Adding intents is must for the bot to work.

you can learn more about intents at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents